# Magento: Custom Field in Billing Info

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I was in the process of adding a custom field in the Magento Billing and checkout process. So far, I have successfully added it in the front-end. But it won't save to the database, so I guess this is where the error lies.

I have already created a module, all with the xml files and mysql files.

The question is...

When I added the field in the phtml files, like the following

```
<input type="text" id="billing:company" name="billing[company]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
```

What exactly is this one?

```
$this->getAddress()->getCompany()
```

And how will I be able to make one for my custom field? For example I added a field with the Ability attribute. Should I have something like the following?

```
$this->getAddress()->getAbility()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @

[Add custom field in the billing and shipping address in the checkout and customer address edit page in frontend and customer addresses details in Admin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend)

Comment: @ R.S, Please look:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794666/issue-while-adding-custom-field-in-billing-address-section-in-magento