# Issue while adding custom field in billing address section in Magento

Tags: php, magento, custom-fields, billing

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend) for inserting new field in billing address section in Magento checkout.

I added `new module`, `form field` in **billing.phtml** page as described in this tutorial. I make sure that the module is enabled in advanced section in admin panel. And the attribute is saved in `eav_attribute`, `sales_flat_order_address`, `sales_flat_quote_address` tables.

The issue is when I make place order the checkout page become broken and nothing can done.

[image]

How can I solve this? Please help..

Comment: Had you checked your error log?

Comment: @Jayson, how can I do this?

Comment: you have to check your error log. refer this URL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203700/where-to-find-log-files-in-magento